# Rspec - address the right generated email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I just want to test user email, so I have this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |u|
      u.sequence(:email) {|n| "user#{n}@example.com" }
      u.first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }       
      u.password "foo123"
  end
end
```

### update

as you see I'm generating the email with `sequence` so now I want to test if I'm pointing to the right email address of a user, as an example I want to send an email to the right user from the `controller`:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

it "should notify user about his profile" do
   @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
   # profile update..
   ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.should include [@user.email]
end
```

above test fails because `user.email` points to a different email address, not the one that is made by FactoryGirl:

```
1) UserController Manage users should notify user about his profile
     Failure/Error: ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.should include [user.email]
       expected [#<Mail::Message:5059500, Multipart: false, Headers: <From: foo <info@foo.com>>, <To: user16@example.com>, <Message-ID: <..41d@linux.mail>>, <Subject: foo>, <Content-Type: text/html>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>] to include ["user15@example.com"]
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -[["user15@example.com"]]
       +[#<Mail::Message:5059500, Multipart: false, Headers: <..>, <From: foo Verticals <info@castaclip.com>>, <To: user16@example.com>, <Message-ID: <..41d@linux.mail>>, <Subject: foo>, <Content-Type: text/html>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>]
```

any help? tnx.

Comment: Can you show more context?  Where are you actually assigning the email to the user?  I presume the goal is not to test your factories...

Comment: `assigns` only makes sense in controller. You only show an example with no context at all, how to debug?

Comment: I update my question to give you a bit more details

Comment: How do you know "user.email points to a different email address"? It's unlike Factory will fail.

Comment: Can you include the previous occurrence of `user.email`, before the matcher line? I need to know what you're comparing it to.

Comment: there is no more occurrence, it seems the `user.email` itself generates a new user with an email address.. not sure.

Comment: Try using `let!(:user)` instead.

Comment: Still the same error, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

What contains in `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` is array of mail objects. You can't expect a mail element to match an email. That's incorrect. Only mail object's `to` method can be compared with email.

You can do like this

```
last_email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
expect(last_email.to).to have_content(user.email)
```

**Add**

OP added this is for multiple emails sent to a group of user. Quite reasonable. I would recommend following method:

Step 1: Clear emails in each example

```
before { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = [] }
```

Step 2: Put all `to` in an array for easy comparison

```
it "will check if email is sent" do
  emails = []
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.each do |m|
    emails << m.to
  end
  expect(emails).to include(user.email)
end
```

**Another note for user issue**: I havn't seen the full code. But if you met the problem of wrong user, it would be safer to use an instance variable instead of `let` to define the factory.

```
# Remove this line
# let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

expect(emails).to include(@user.email)
```

Comment: So this approach fails if you send multiple emails upon this action, then last is not pointing to email address that you wish to address.

Comment: @stsd, you just created one user, how to send multiple emails? Even if multiple emails, there are ways around, but not for this case.

Comment: the reason that I used `include` is because I'm dealing with multiple emails. I update the question plz have a look.

Comment: thanks, looks nice; but the problem still exist because the `user.email` pointing to a different email; plz have a look to the `rspec` error in above.

Comment: @stsd, did you see my "Another note"?

Comment: If I use `@user = Factory...` then I'll be into a big problem because the `user` model has many other relationships and then I need to update a lot of other tests..

Comment: @stsd, I don't understand your point at all. Using `let` will do exactly the same in factory. The only difference is variable context in test.

Comment: I updated the test now I use `@user=..` but I still have the same issue,  plz have a look to the updated test.